# how to convert my Webclient to send Post request instead of Get request

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, webclient

I am working on an asp.net mvc-5 web application. and I have the following WebClient which will send a Get request as follow:-

```
using (WebClient wc = new WebClient())
            {
                string url = currentURL+ "home/scanserver?FQDN=allscan";
                wc.Headers.Add("Authorization", token);
                var json =wc.DownloadStringTaskAsync(url);
               TempData["messagePartial"] = string.Format("Scan has been completed. Scan reported generated");

            }
```

so can anyone advice how I can force my webclient to send Post request instead of Get request, while sending the same token (inside the request header) + FQDN parameter ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [UploadStringTaskAsync](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh193920(v=vs.110).aspx) instead of `DownloadStringTaskAsync`.

```
   var url = currentURL+ "home/scanserver";
   wc.Headers.Add("Authorization", token);
   var json =wc.UploadStringTaskAsync(url, "FQDN=allscan");
```

**NOTE** that `json` is a `Task<string>` not a `string`.  Are you sure that you want to use async behaviour?

Comment: @yes I want to use async behaviour , and the the home/scanserver  action method is an async Task also..

Comment: thanks for the help,  I can now send http post using UploadStringTaskAsync() , but on the Post ScanServer action method I am unable to reference the FQDN parameter that is being passed. I tried the           "string    FQDN = Request.Form["FQDN"];" also I tried defining the FQDN inside the action method  as follow:- "public async Task<ActionResult> ScanServer(string FQDN)" but did not work either..